# Specify XPath to count the value of a set of child-nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to specify an XPath query such that it can count the number at the text-value of a set of children:

This is best explained with an example, for instance:

```
    <badge_counts>
        <gold>2</gold>
        <silver>15</silver>
        <bronze>32</bronze>
    </badge_counts>
```

Thus, is it possible to specify an Xpath, to get `total_badges = 49`. (from: 2+15+32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
sum(/*/*)
```

This produces the sum, of the string-values converted to number, of all elements in the XML document that are children of the top element of the document.

**As a rule**: Whenever possible try to avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator, because this may lead to unwanted inefficient evaluation -- many XPath engines in this case perform complete traversal of the whole tree rooted in the context node.

**XSLT - based verification**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<badge_counts>
    <gold>2</gold>
    <silver>15</silver>
    <bronze>32</bronze>
</badge_counts>
```

**evaluates the XPath expression and outputs the result**:

```
49
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I’m just trying to test here http://www.xpathtester.com/test, but seems to be returning an error. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Larry: You can download and use a better tool -- the XPath Visualizer -- at: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Comment: @Larry: I updated the answer with a XSLT - based verification that anybody can run and verify that the provided XPath expression produces the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sum(//badge_counts/*/text())
```

Python example:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.XML("""<badge_counts><gold>2</gold><silver>15</silver><bronze>32</bronze></badge_counts>""")
>>> doc.xpath('//badge_counts/*/text()')
['2', '15', '32']
>>> doc.xpath('sum(//badge_counts/*/text())')
49.0
```